# PHP - Restler returns 404 when I put a value that contains a slash

Tags: php, api, rest, restler

I am using Restler and I have a function that receive a string. That string may contain a slash. Example: "/a/b/id"

```
http://test/test.json//a/b/id
```

Whenever I use a slash in the field it returns a 404

I am sure that the value will return something, but i really need to use slash in the string.

If I try to use the id by itself, no slash, it returns the correct value, but to do that I put the slashs hardcoded (not cool)

```
http://test/test.json/id
```

Any tips?

Is this a bug?

thanks

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189033/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you know that your parameter may contain slash, avoid using them as url parameter

make them as query string or body parameter instead

here is an example http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_001_helloworld/say/hello?to=slash/slash

Comment: I have similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531596/restler-can-not-process-url-with-dot-and-returns-404 But need to have it as path can not use query parameter.