# Restler can not process URL with dot and returns 404

Tags: php, parameters, restler

I need to call URL https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/image/upload3/w_300/v1675261380/nvrzhquqawhrkxlex6le.jpg
I have an endpoint on Restler which looks like this:

```
/**
 * image api
 *
 * @status 200
 * @url GET xxx/image/upload3/{params}/{dir}/{id}
 *
 * @param mixed $params {@from path}
 * @param mixed $dir {@from path}
 * @param mixed $id {@from path}
 *
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws RestException
 */
public function screenshot($params, $dir, $id)
{
    die('xxx');
    $this->showImage($params, $dir, $id);
}
```

But Restelr returns 404 before the function `screenshot()` is called and `die('xxx')` never run. If I remove the .jpg from URL it works so I am pretty sure the problem is in the .jpg suffix. I tried to use `{@patern}` param but it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I uses a wildcard pattern in your route configuration to capture everything in the `$id` parameter, including the `.jpg` extension, see if this helps

```
/**
 * image api
 *
 * @status 200
 * @url GET xxx/image/upload3/{params}/{dir}/{id}
 *
 * @param mixed $params {@from path}
 * @param mixed $dir {@from path}
 * @param mixed $id {@from path} {@pattern /[\w\-\.]+/}
 *
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws RestException
 */
public function screenshot($params, $dir, $id)
{
   die('xxx');
  $this->showImage($params, $dir, $id);
}
```

Comment: Do you get 404 if you dont use the @patern?

Comment: depends on how your routing system handles parameters without a defined pattern. some frameworks or routing systems may automatically capture everything after the last slash in a route as a parameter, even without a specific pattern. BUT if your routing system requires explicit patterns to correctly interpret and capture URL segments, removing the pattern might lead to a 404 error, as the route may not correctly match URLs with extensions.